# How to change the default size of the eclipse inspect wizard window

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse when we debug an application, at times we do, inspect on a variable by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and then we get an inspect wizard which shows the value or values in the variable in focus. Can we modify the default size of this window? It always appears at a very small size at least in my Windows machine?

I am not asking about the font size of the text, I am asking about the **window size** itself. By the way if I get to know how to increase the font as well that would be really awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. See [Eclipse bug 332387 - Inspect Window does not remember being resized](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=332387). Vote for the bug or/and add a comment if it's important to you.

As a workaround, use the pop-up window that is shown on mouse hovering and that remember its size or use the *Expressions* view (hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> two times).

The font size can be increased in *Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts: Debug > Variable text font*. But unfortunately, the hight of the rows of the table tree is not adapted and the text is cropped at the bottom. Please report this bug to Eclipse.

Comment: Can you explain last part Expression view (2x Ctrl + Shift + I)

Comment: If you hit Ctrl+Shift+I twice, the selected expression will be added to the _Expressions_ view.

Comment: The inspect popup window from mouse hover does NOT remember its size either. Been using that since 2018.

Comment: @MasterHD Go ahead, make a pull request [here](https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.debug) or [here](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform).